# How to Display the Numerical Value of Multiple Database Values via an HTML Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a page in which I want to display "how many" from values in my database. I've attached a picture of what I have so far.
From my current count I know I have 13 transportation items, 2 communications items, etc., so I'm wondering how to output that properly.

[image]

```
<?php

    $countSQL = "SELECT username, primary_function, COUNT(*)
                FROM resource
                WHERE primary_function 
                IN ('transportation', 'communications', 'engineering', 'search and rescue', 'education', 'energy', 'firefighting', 'human services')
                GROUP BY username, primary_function";
    $countresult = mysqli_query($conn, $countSQL);
    $countdata= mysqli_num_rows($countresult);

        $sql = "SELECT pf_id, primary_function FROM primary_function ORDER BY pf_id;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($queryResult > 0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              echo "<tr><td>". $row['pf_id'] ."</td><td>". $row['primary_function'] ."</td><td>". $countdata."</td></td>";
            }
          }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias for your `COUNT(*)`, ie `resourceCount`

```
SELECT username, primary_function, COUNT(*) as resourceCount
```

then create an array with the `primary_function` and `resourceCount`

```
$resourceCounts = array();
while ($rowCounts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($countresult)) {
    $resourceCounts['primary_function'] = $rowCounts['resourceCount'];
}
```

Then in your table, use the `$row['primary_function']` to get the `resourceCount` -> `$resourceCounts[$row['primary_function']]`

```
echo "<tr><td>". $row['pf_id'] ."</td><td>". $row['primary_function'] ."</td><td>". $resourceCounts[$row['primary_function']] ."</td></td>";
```

To get your final total, create a counter var and add that value to it -

```
$total = 0;
....
// add the value in the loop
$total += $resourceCounts[$row['primary_function']];
....
```

Comment: I appreciate this!
I'm wondering if there's just something else wrong with my code, because now Total Resources column is blank after inputting $row['resourceCount'].

Comment: I didn't realize your `$row` array was from your 2nd query, so what I did will not work. I will work on a different approach

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'm currently experimenting with Union, and seemingly making a bit progress, but things are not aligned properly in the HTML table columns.